# Writing into a device file prints "Invalid argument"

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I am currently working on a device driver where I want to write a sentence to that driver and display it in the kernel. Reading an internal buffer and calling the driver with *cat* works perfectly fine. However, if I try to write to the device driver it returns the following message:
[image]

I have the following code for my device driver. I can't seem to find where I went wrong in my write function...

```
#include "device_file.h"
#include <linux/fs.h>       /* file stuff */
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* printk() */
#include <linux/errno.h>    /* error codes */
#include <linux/module.h>   /* THIS_MODULE */
#include <linux/cdev.h>     /* char device stuff */
#include <linux/uaccess.h>  /* copy_to_user() */

static const char g_s_Hello_World_string[] = "Hello from Job & Arief!\n\0";
static const ssize_t g_s_Hello_World_size = sizeof(g_s_Hello_World_string);
static char memory_buffer[500];

/*===============================================================================================*/
static ssize_t device_file_read(struct file *file_ptr, char __user *user_buffer, size_t count, loff_t *possition){

    printk( KERN_NOTICE "Kurniawan_Meulenbeld-driver: Device file is read at offset = %i, read bytes count = %u\n"
    , (int)*possition
    , (unsigned int)count );

    if( *possition >= g_s_Hello_World_size )
    return 0;

    if( *possition + count > g_s_Hello_World_size )
    count = g_s_Hello_World_size - *possition;

    if( copy_to_user(user_buffer, g_s_Hello_World_string + *possition, count) != 0 )
    return -EFAULT;

    *possition += count;
    return count;
}

/*===============================================================================================*/
static ssize_t memory_write( struct file *filp, const char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos) {
    const char *tmp;
    tmp=buf+count-1;

    if( copy_from_user(memory_buffer,tmp,1) != 0 )
        return -EFAULT;

    return count;
}
/*===============================================================================================*/
static struct file_operations Kurniawan_Meulenbeld_driver_fops =
        {
                .owner = THIS_MODULE,
                .read = device_file_read,
                .write =  memory_write,
        };

static int device_file_major_number = 0;
static const char device_name[] = "Kurniawan_Meulenbeld-driver";

/*===============================================================================================*/
int register_device(void)
{
    int result = 0;

    printk( KERN_NOTICE "Kurniawan_Meulenbeld-driver: register_device() is called.\n" );

    result = register_chrdev( 0, device_name, &Kurniawan_Meulenbeld_driver_fops );
    if( result < 0 )
    {
        printk( KERN_WARNING "Kurniawan_Meulenbeld-driver:  can\'t register character device with errorcode = %i\n", result );
        return result;
    }

    device_file_major_number = result;
    printk( KERN_NOTICE "Kurniawan_Meulenbeld-driver: registered character device with major number = %i and minor numbers 0...255\n"
            , device_file_major_number );

    return 0;
}

/*===============================================================================================*/
void unregister_device(void)
{
    printk( KERN_NOTICE "Kurniawan_Meulenbeld-driver: unregister_device() is called\n" );
    if(device_file_major_number != 0)
    {
        unregister_chrdev(device_file_major_number, device_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its very difficult to read the imaged message.  If you can it would be better to edit your post to include the text version of the message into the body of the post.

Comment: Not sure if its contributing, but declaring `tmp` with `const`, then modifying it in the very next line seems odd. might be better to do `const char tmp = buf + count -1;`, then pass its address below:  `copy_from_user(memory_buffer, &tmp,1)`

Comment: @J.Meulenbeld What is the meaning of the character '\0' in the string literal static const char g_s_Hello_World_string[] = "Hello from Job & Arief!\n\0";?!

Comment: You want: `copy_from_user(memory_buffer, buf, count)`. Check `count` against 500 beforehand. `buf` should have `_user` on it. Later you'll need to honor `f_pos`

Comment: J.Meulenbeld, Note that `g_s_Hello_World_size` is 26 and not 25.  Was that part of your plan - to point to a character array with 2 _null characters_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that redirection `>/dev/my-driver` is done by the shell under the current user before `sudo` is invoked. `EINVAL` from [`write`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) means *fd is attached to an object which is unsuitable for writing*.

It is not clear whether `hello` is a file or a string. `cat` expects it to be a file.

To write string `hello` into your device try:

```
echo "hello" | sudo tee /dev/my-driver
```

To write file `hello` into your device try:

```
cat hello | sudo tee /dev/my-driver
# or
sudo tee /dev/my-driver <hello
```